Autograd in Pytorch Lightning in Trainstep
I would like to implement a Pytorch Lightning based ML Training, where I use the autograd functionalty for train loss calculation:
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch
    y_hat = self(x)
    loss = self.loss_function(y_hat, y)
    return loss

Every sample of X, x, is a two dimensional vector x = [v, a].
In the train step, I want to calc the gradient of y_hat w.r.t. to v.
Loss is further calculated by:
loss = mse(y,y_hat) + mse(gradient,gradient_hat)

Where the (true) gradient is given.
Trying so far the (typical) way of y_hat.backward(), without getring it to work:
def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
    x, y = batch
    x.requires_grad_(True)  # Ensure we track gradients for x
    y_hat = self(x)
        
    # Calculate gradients of y_hat with respect to v (x[:, 0])
    v = x[:, 0]
    grads = torch.autograd.grad(y_hat, v, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(y_hat), create_graph=True)[0] # ...

